# Adding elements of a structure in Intel X86

Tags: x86, sum, structure, intel, masm

We have a structure defined:

```
Employee struct
     name DB 20 dup(0)
     salary DW 0
Employee ends

nrEmployees DW 4
Employees Employee {"Alex", 100}, {"Mike", 100}, {"Paul", 300} {"Ana", 450}
sum DD 0
```

How do we find the sum of all the salaries from the Employees, using Intel X86 assembly language?

Comment: 1) what assmebler you are using? 2) what have you tried so far? 3) "some code:" - where's the code? You only showed us the data

Comment: X86 assembly language

Comment: Ok, got it, I'm using OllyDbg

Comment: The assembler itself is MASM

Answer (score 0):

So the code to find the sum can be:

```
.code
start:
mov EAX, 0
mov EBX, 0
mov ECX, 0
lea EAX, Employees
mov EBX, [EAX + 20]
add ECX, EBX
ADD EAX, 22
mov EBX, [EAX + 20]
add ECX, EBX
ADD EAX, 22
mov EBX, [EAX + 20]
add ECX, EBX
ADD EAX, 22
mov EBX, [EAX + 20]
add ECX, EBX
mov SUM, ECX
```

It is with-out loops, just a simple way to work with the structures and registers

Comment: If you're not going to loop, you should simplify by putting the +22 into the addressing mode.  And you're loading 4 bytes, not 2, from the `dw` at the end of the struct.  Use `movzx ecx, word ptr  [eax + 20 + 22*0]` / `movzx edx, word ptr [eax + 20 + 22*1]` / `add ecx, edx` / etc.  Or make it a `dd` and use `add ecx, [eax + 20 + 22*1]` repeated 3 times with `*1`, `*2`, `*3`.  (Notice that instead of adding the first one to zero, we just load it directly.  This is another simplification that fully unrolling allows.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, the code this way is a lot shorter.

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer with that, especially the bugfix to only read a `word` instead of a `dword`.